# adding sharing buttons (like "addtoany") to a single image in lightbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sharing

I have developed my own theme in wordpress using bootstrap.

I am using lightbox for image gallery and I am both trying to add sharing buttons on a single image opened in pop up,both trying to excercise a bit in using Jquery.

The single image in lightbox of course comes without the option of sharing buttons for social network.

the `div` that contains the image is an element to consider, and then there is the code of the snippet. i tried to do this...

```
$sharingButtons = $("</div>");
$sharingButtons.css({top: 100, left: 20, 'absolute'});

$sharingButtons.addClass("");

$sharingButtons.appendTo( '.lb-outerContainer' );

$('lb-outerContainer').append("<div class='addtoany_share_save_container addtoany_content_bottom'><div style='line-height: 32px;' class='a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 addtoany_list a2a_target' id=''> )etc...  (here all the snippet code of addtoany)...

</div></div>");

 $('img.lb-outerContainer').css("opacity", "0.8");
```

the element $sharingbuttons is the div that contains the snippet...

it does not work., anyone has better ideas?

I use last version of Jquery.

thanks
Paolo
p.s. do i have to use 
"Insert After" to add a div beside the lb-outer container_? 
you can view my website here
http://www.paolobergomi.it/new-gallery/indoor-portraits/

if yo uclick on an image, i wish that on the right, in vertical layout..just attached to the image, appear the list of the sharing buttons
i guess insertAfter could be an option? thanks to EO
added:
I would start like this?

$("

and then add the snippet code of addtoany in the new div?
any tips? thanks

paolo

Comment: $("</div").insertAfter(".lb-outerContainer");
});
could be ok?

Answer (score 1):

After you append your a2a div code, you need to execute the function a2a.init('page') because the addtoany script need to add your new code. First of all, insert a class a2a_target, an ID for the div and create a javascript code like above:

```
$('lb-outerContainer').append("<div class='addtoany_share_save_container addtoany_content_bottom'><div style='line-height: 32px;' class='a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 addtoany_list a2a_target' id='myShareLinks'> )etc...  (here all the snippet code of addtoany)...

a2a_config.target = '#myShareLinks';
a2a.init('page');
```

Note: a2a_config and a2a are global variables created by addtoany script.